# Is $T$ is a topology on $\mathbb{Z}$ ? yes/no

Tags: general-topology

let  $n \in \mathbb{Z}^+$

$T = \{ \emptyset \} \cup \{n\mathbb{Z}\}$

Is   $T$ is  a topology on $\mathbb{Z}$ ?

I thinks yes  because here $\emptyset$ and $\{n\mathbb{Z}\}$ are in  $T$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, unless $n=1$, because otherwise $\mathbb Z\notin T$.